# Get Event Class

Tags: c#, events, event-handling

```
 var obj=new Button();
 string eventName = "Click";

 var evt = obj.GetType().GetEvent(eventName);

 EventHandler myCode = delegate {MessageBox.Show("asd");};
evt.AddEventHandler(obj, myCode);
```

hi
I am adding event handler to button clicks event this code
 click event has need to 2 parametr object sender and EventArgs e

How can i get EventArgs e parametr in this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean "in the handler", then:

```
EventHandler myCode = delegate (object sender, EventArgs e) {
         MessageBox.Show("asd");};
```

or more dense as a lambda:

```
EventHandler myCode = (sender, e) => MessageBox.Show("asd");
```

If you mean "when invoking the event", use `obj` and `EventArgs.Empty`.

Comment: I am using other Reflection there is a void in my dll and i will send my paramers to there like

Main Code

{

Assembly reflection

 var obj=new Button();
 string eventName = "Click";

 var evt = obj.GetType().GetEvent(eventName);

 EventHandler myCode = delegate {MessageBox.Show("asd");};
evt.AddEventHandler(obj, myCode);

here How Can I send to parametrs? Maybe not EventArg KeyEventArgs




}


MyDLL
void Button_Click(object sender,EventArgs e)
{

CODES


}

Comment: In that scenario, I *believe* that `Delegate.CreateDeletgate` to a pre-existing method should be able to shim over the gaps.